# Where are ontouch() events allow to be? Why not on DIV's?

Tags: html, touch, w3c-validation

validator.w3.org is is throwing an error:

**Attribute ontouchmove not allowed on element div at this point.**

On the following code:

```
<div id="someDiv" ontouchmove="onTouchmove(event)" ontouchend="noTouch(event)"></div>
```

Doctype is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

*What elements are touch events allowed on?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep it out of the dom

With jQuery it would look like:

```
$('#someDiv').live('ontouchmove',function(e){
    onTouchmove(e);
});

$('#someDiv').live('ontouchend',function(e){
    noTouch(e);
});
```

Comment: the way my page functions, it seemed to make more sense for it to be in the tag (onclick's and such never caused me any problems).This works like a charm. stuck it in an `$(document).ready(function(){});`, and voila -- VALID!

Comment: Isn't that a great feeling? :)